# Spacing around \cdot when used as a wildcard

Tags: spacing

I have to use `\cdot` as a *wildcard* indicator in an expression like: `K(\cdot,y)`.

My concern is: is the spacing around the `\cdot` correct? should I force something in either one side or the other of it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If it's a placeholder, I'd use `{\cdot}`. But in the example you have given, the spacing is already correct because neither `(` nor `,` is seen as an ordinary character as would `5` and `x` in `5 \cdot x`. (There's no harm to use `{\cdot}` anyway, maybe as a macro: `\newcommand*\wildcard{{\cdot}}`.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Thanks @qrrbrbirlbel. Indeed, it is used as a placeholder and unfortunately it looks (at least to me) awful (not enough space around). Thus I was wondering about about its standard use.

Comment: I don't know about a standard use, but similar to the notation of a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) a spacing to what `{}\cdot{}` produces seem appropriate, too. I guess, it depends on typographical consensus and an author's individual choice. Either way: Use a macro for this, so you can later change its definition without having to correct your whole document manually.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, That is exactly what I need, thank you! I would be glad to mark it as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*For what it's worth, this is converted from comments. I'm no expert on mathematical typography, so these are if anything suggestions.*

---

My first idea was

```
K({\cdot},y)
```

which produces the same spacing as

```
K(\cdot,y)
```

because neither `(` nor `,` is treated as an ordinary character as `5` and `x` would be in `5 \cdot x`.

If you rather want to reproduce the spacing from `5 \cdot x` you can use empty groups to fake them.

```
K({}\cdot{},y)
```

does look more like something like

```
K(x,y)
```

You can, of course, specify any space around the `\cdot` with `\mspace` or the primitive `\mkern` which both take dimensions in `mu` (math unit: `mu` = `1/18 em`):

```
{{\mkern 2mu\cdot\mkern 2mu}}
```

I recommend to define a macro for this kind of wildcard/placeholder so that, if you ever change your opinion about the *correct* spacing you can just change the macro's definition (aka “The LaTeX way”).

```
\newcommand*\wc{{\mkern 2mu\cdot\mkern 2mu}}
```

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\wc{{}\cdot{}}
\begin{document}\noindent
\( K (  \cdot  , y ) \) \\
\( K ({ \cdot} , y ) \) \\
\( K ({}\cdot{}, y ) \) \\
\( K (  \wc    , y ) \) \\
\( K (        x, y ) \)
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: The "correct" space depends on many factors; slightly less space around the dot can be obtained by `\newcommand\blank{{\mkern 2mu\cdot\mkern 2mu}}`. I ***definitely*** recommend using a command for it.