# Spacing around \cdot

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I'm trying to use `\cdot`as a dummy for a function argument in the following expression

```
C(\cdot\mid\mathcal{F}_{t-1})
```

However, the above produces more space to the right of the dot than to the left. I'd like the spacing to be symmetrical. I've tried using `{}`on either side but haven't been able to get the desired result.

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78165/spacing-around-cdot-when-used-as-a-wildcard) is quite similar. Maybe it answers your question too.

Comment: The trouble is not with `\cdot` but with `\mid`, which is a relation. You would get equal (but small) spacing using `{\mid}`, but I wouldn't suggest that. Isn't `C(\,\cdot\mid\mathcal{F}_{t-1})` enough?

Comment: That is better but still not perfectly symmetrical. Perhaps it would be better to use an alternative to `\mid` that isn't a relation. I'm just not sure such a thing exists.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you want to use the blank next either between an opening atom (the open parenthesis) and a relation atom (`\mid`) or between a relation atom and a closing atom, you can define `\blank` to be a relation symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\blank}{\mathrel{\;\cdot\;}}

\begin{document}

$C(\blank \mid F_{t-1})$

$C(x \mid \blank)$

\end{document}
```

The trick is that TeX doesn't add space in cases

> **Open Rel Rel**

or

> **Rel Rel Close**

[image]

Comment: If `\blank` is to be used in a different context, such as “blank+x”, then `{\blank}+x` should do.

Comment: Why not just make the widened `\cdot` an `ord` here?  Then it would be in the same category as `x`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann The spacing would be asymmetric. It would be right if instead of `\mid` a comma was used.